# Summing numbers after string

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following data stored in a file:

```
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:1 minnumber3:0 minnumber4:0 maxnumber2number3:1 maxnumber3:0 maxnumber4:0 no. of number5 per bucket:35 num:
number1:0 number2=0 minnumber2number3:3 minnumber3:3 minnumber4:11577215 maxnumber2number3:3 maxnumber3:3 maxnumber4:14707215 no. of number5 per bucket:6 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:1 minnumber3:0 minnumber4:0 maxnumber2number3:3 maxnumber3:1 maxnumber4:1882188 no. of number5 per bucket:8 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:2 minnumber3:248 minnumber4:10000000 maxnumber2number3:2 maxnumber3:248 maxnumber4:10000000 no. of number5 per bucket:91 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:2 minnumber3:239 minnumber4:11641499 maxnumber2number3:2 maxnumber3:244 maxnumber4:2248700 no. of number5 per bucket:8999 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:2 minnumber3:251 minnumber4:2000000 maxnumber2number3:2 maxnumber3:251 maxnumber4:2000000 no. of number5 per bucket:8986 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:2 minnumber3:232 minnumber4:14775115 maxnumber2number3:1 maxnumber3:0 maxnumber4:0 no. of number5 per bucket:6385 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:2 minnumber3:253 minnumber4:9404695 maxnumber2number3:1 maxnumber3:0 maxnumber4:0 no. of number5 per bucket:8863 num:
number1:0 number2=1 minnumber2number3:3 minnumber3:3 minnumber4:14777215 maxnumber2number3:1 maxnumber3:0 maxnumber4:0 no. of number5 per bucket:2679 num:
```

Now I need to retrieve all numbers after "no. of number5 per bucket:" and sum them up. For example I need to sum the following:

```
35 
6 
8 
91 
8999
8986 
6385 
8863
2679
```

I know I can do the same using programming language like python, but I am learning linux commands is there some linux command like grep, etc. which can help me do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sed:

`sed -e 's/^.*bucket://' | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z]*:$//'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied by selecting the column by number:

```
tr ":" " " <table | awk '{print $21}'
```

Assuming your data is in file `table`, the first command translates `:` to space and the second gets the 21st column.

**EDIT**: Pure `awk` by specifying the field separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ :]"} {print $21}' table
```

**2nd EDIT**: Selecting with `grep` and summing with `awk`:

```
grep -oE "no\. of number5 per bucket:[^ ]*" table | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {S+=$2} END{print S}'
```

**3rd EDIT**: After reading Anton's solution, I was reminded, that you can also use `sed` to match the name and get the solution in a group (`\1`)

```
sed -rn 's/^.*no\. of number5 per bucket:([0-9]*).*/\1/p' table | awk '{S+=$1} END {print S}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple bash script will also do:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sum=0

while read -r line; do 
    n=${line##*number5 per bucket:}
    sum+=$((${n% num:}))
done <"$1"

printf "\n the sum is: %d\n\n" $sum
```

**Output**

```
$ bash script.sh filename

 the sum is: 36052
```